# C# LINQ, Remove all elements that are equal

Tags: c#, linq, list

If I for example have list of doubles

```
  List<double> values = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
```

And I get new values

```
 List<double> newVals = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 9, 6, 2, 7 };

// Output I woud look for is 1 2 3 0 0 0 7
```

We know they are both equal size but some of the values have changed.
I heard that with LINQ we can keep all values that are equal but remove the new values at their indexes.

I have tried using the Except method but as far as I know it gives just the differences in an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [Zip](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfKcbQ) function is what you're looking for.

```
var list1 = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var list2 = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 9, 6, 2, 7 };
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (x1, x2) => x1 == x2 ? x1 : 0); // 1 2 3 0 0 0 7
```

It takes two lists and selects a result using an expression with the paired item in each list as arguments to the select expression.

```
1) x1 = 1; x2 = 1; result = 1;
...
4) x1 = 4; x2 = 9; result = 0;
...
7) x1 = 7; x2 = 7; result = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `Linq` statement.

```
var result = values.Select((v, i) => v== newVals[i] ? v:0);
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OOssQ9)

Comment: Wow, I was not aware there was an overload on `Select` that allows for the index to be passed to the expression.